# Can't configure Spring Security with jdbc data source

Tags: java, xml, spring, jdbc, spring-security

I've never had a deal with spring security earlier, but I need to use it. And I can't configure it.

My **applicationContext-security.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config='true'>


        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/registr*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.css" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.js" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/index.htm"
                             default-target-url="/mytime.htm"
                             authentication-failure-url="/index.htm"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
       <security:authentication-provider>
               <security:jdbc-user-service
                   data-source-ref="dataSource"
                   users-by-username-query="select login, password from users where login = ?"/>
       </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbcMySQL.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
</beans>
```

My **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>encoding</param-name>
          <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

But I have: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 61; columnNumber: 227; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'data-source-ref' is not allowed to appear in element 'security:user-service'.

Please, show me my mistakes.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that there is a 'data-source-ref' attribute in a 'security:user-service' element. Am I missing something? Maybe there is an older version of the file still cached somewhere, have you tried cleaning the project?

Answer (score 1):

Try extract data source description to a separate file **security-datasource.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
         "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
</beans>
```

Also you should have **propertyConfigurer** that show where to find file with the properties to replace placeholders like `${jdbc.driverClassName}`, `${jdbc.url}`, `${jdbc.username}` and `${jdbc.password}`.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
```

Content of file **jdbc.properties** (put it into **src/main/resources/** folder):

```
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you also need `authorities-by-username-query` in `security:jdbc-user-service` element

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
```

Spring Security expects resultset to be `username, password, enabled`. If the columns in your DB are with different names you can use alias: `select login as username...`. You can also "hard-code" some value: `select login as username, password, 1 as enabled from users where login=?`

Here are the docs for the element: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-jdbc-user-service